# API to get NFT Floor Price

Tags: nft, api, cnft.io

Does anyone know of a public API that I can use to get the floor price for ALL Cardano NFT projects. I have created a Database listing all the Cardano NFT projects (currently there are just over 5000 NFT projects). I have tried https://api.opencnft.io/1/ - which works perfectly and is exactly what I need, however, their limit of 60 requests per min does not allow me to update my DB as the script fails after about 275 requests...

Answer (score 1):

Since the only downside to using the opencnft api seems to be the rate limit, then perhaps you can reach out to them directly and ask for a raise to the limit?

Twitter:
@opencnft
@Kakulukian

I do notice, however, that there hasn't been any activity from either of the above Twitter handles since March 31st.